# Change one element for each click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a box , like this :

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

And i want to do something with jquery that changes the text of that element for each time that the `.box` get clicked !

For example,

for first time , i click on the box, i want to have : `<div class="box">Test1</div>`

For second time , i click on that , i want this : `<div class="box">Test2</div>`

+...

I khow i can use this code for click event :

```
$('.box').click(function(){
 $(this).text();
});
```

But i want something to do , to have multiple values for each click !

***EDit : 
I don't need a value + count ! i need new string each time***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that code:

```
var myTexts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

$('div.box').click(function (indexOfArray) {
    $(this).text(myTexts[indexOfArray]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but not worked for me.. can u add JSFIDDLE ?

Answer (score 1):

try to store your click count in a variable.

```
   var i = 0;
   $('.box').click(function(){
     i++;
     $(this).text('Test'+i);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var clix = 1;
$('div.box').click(function () {
    $(this).text('Test' + clix++);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QdnR4/1)**

Comment: thanks, i don't need test + count ! How can i have a new string with new click ?

Comment: What kind of new string?

Comment: first one can be `test` and for new click : `message` and for third time : `Hello!`

Comment: Then you need to specify what these news strings are. Your question isn't clear. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fujaN/?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angstrey/GCGBS/1/)

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        count = $this.data("count") || 0;

    count += 1;
    $this.text("Test" + count.toString());

    $this.data("count", count);
});
```

Comment: thanks, i don't need test + count ! How can i have a new string with new click ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Would you mind specifying? Your original post said to put "Test1", "Test2", and so on.

Comment: No, the secound one can be `Messaeg` , the third one can be `Hello!` and so on . there is no increasing in number, just new strings

Comment: You will need to store those guys in an array and then reference them in the counter. You can update your post to indicate that.